# Can Flyway find out and generate migration files from datamodel?

Tags: flyway

Ey everyone! :)

I have been having a look at Flyway but I am not sure about how I can use it. In my case, I have an entity model (annotated using JPA) and, for me, the useful it would be that FlyWay could find out the changes on my model every time I call "migration" and generate the migration files. That is the way such as Rails works (Rails uses a DSL but I hope you understand what I mean). As I have read in the wiki, Flyway does not work in that way but needs the migration files (sql or Java).

If I integrated Flyway in my application (programmatic), could I generate those migration files? I think the answer is "no", that way only would give me control over migrations from Java code.
Am I right?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

This is not currently supported.

Feel free to file a request in the issue tracker: https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues?state=open

Answer (score 1):

Flyway would have to delegate this to the jpa implementation you're using so it would be tricky.

What I would suggest however is that you use the JPA implementation to generate migration scripts that you then plugin into flyway. It's fairly simple with openjpa, don't know about the others.