# Given I have to write the migration scripts myself, what value does Flyway provide?

Tags: database, database-migration, flyway

In my situation I use a tool that generates SQL statements to contain all database init/create statements. How does Flyway provide value beyond what my tool provides? Why should I care to write hand-coded migration scripts to use Flyway?

Answer (score 2):

The question above mixes two things that should be separate: the concept of database creation mixed with the concept of migration.

**database creation**

Given a complete database and an empty database, you can use many tools to generate the scripts needed to recreate the complete database where nothing exists. In Flyway terms, you just creating a baseline. This isn't the concept of migration at all. Of course, given a V2.0 database, you could see any V1.0 database, blow it away, and install the V2.0 database, but now you've lost your data.

**migration**

Given a complete database V2.0 and a V1.0 older database, and you want to make the V1.0 database be "upgraded" to the V2.0. In the database world, this is called a **migration** because the existing 1.0 data needs to be re-arranged in a way that it works on V2.0. Now you need a script that not only creates/alters tables, you need a script that does some ETL (extract data, transform the data to be able to load into the new table structures, alter the old database to the new table structures, then load the data into the database). This may or may not be trivial, depending. You build the script to do it, Flyway will manage executing that script.

**Flyway**

Flyway enables the following:

- Migration scripts become part of the software asset. They are versioned so that baseline/migration scripts can be maintained in source control in a way that migration becomes a repeatable feature as opposed to "one off" scripting work.
- Flyway maintains a meta table in each database it works with so it knows what scripts have been applied
- Flyway can apply migration in a completely automated way that removes manual execution errors
- Flyway enables the creation of migration scripts as part of development (like Test Driven Development makes unit test creation an integral part of development) so that all your database development is captured in the form of migration scripts (rather than building migration scripts as needed as part of "one off" migrations.
- It's common when using Flyway to update any previous version of your application in seconds via a single command. It becomes so easy that the stress of migration from an old DB to a new version goes away and now, evolution of the DB becomes easy and usual.

To use Flyway well, it requires changing your workflow: every time develop a change in your developer DB, put the change into a migration script so you can execute those changes against all the older DB versions that exist in the world. And those scripts are checked into your application's source code making migration a first class citizen of your software asset just like any other functionality.

Answer (score 0):

It depends very much on your use case,

If you plan to write a simple application with an database structure that will remain static over the lifetime of the application it will add very little value.

If the project is expected to have a dynamic design over its lifetime with changes taking place on the schema Flyway provides a formal structure in which the changes maybe expressed and viewed. This formal structure can also be very helpful if you end up with a larger team working on the project as Flyway can then become part of the framework to handle things like multi-schema CI work.

One key thing is that you do not have to start with Flyway, you can added it at a later point, normally with limited retooling as the schema at that point in time will just become your baseline to which all future changes can be added.

Comment: I had a long discussion with Lance on the topic and the core essence of the tooling is to allow scaleability in terms of development time and structural complexity of the application that uses the database. If you have non of the two, then of course you do not necessarily need it. Nevertheless this is only partially true as today nobody would claim that unit tests are "not necessary", but some years back people would say: "only use it if your application is really complex...". Which brings me back to Lance's answer that refers to unit testing being similar to these type of tools.